# *** missing separator despite using tabs

Tags: makefile

Asking this question is my last resort. I try to run "make all" and I get the error

```
Makefile:457: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

on the the line with cloc (second line).

```
linecount:
    cloc --read-lang-def=$(PROJECT).cloc \
         src/$(PROJECT) include/$(PROJECT) tools examples \
         python matlab
```

I changed spaces to tabs both on that line and inside the file $(PROJECT).cloc. However, the error persists. And it only appears on that line. I am at a loss.

Comment: Watch out for single spaces. Use an editor that can show whitespace characters.

Comment: You can hexdump the file and look at exactly what's going on. Maybe there is a non-printable character

Comment: Are you 100% that the `\` characters are really at the end of their line? No trailing spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Use `vim` or `vi` to open makefile then write `:set list` it will show you all the spaces and tabs. Tabs are ^I and line endings are ^$ . Make sure your indentation is always with tabs instead of spaces or even 4 spaces. 4 spaces doesn't make a tab in makefile you should use tabs for indentation. You can make this with other editors as well.

Comment: Why would you want to replace the tab with spaces?

Comment: Thank you for the comment i wrote that wrong. You should use only tabs. Because makefile doesn't accept spaces or 4 spaces. It only allows tabs. I corrected my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing as in Alperen's answer with `nano` by opening the makefile and using the key combination `alt+shift+p` to enable whitespace display where tabs will be represented by a `>` character and spaces by a `.` character. This will indicate what `make` is 'seeing' at the beginning of that line, it may not be a tab character despite what it may seem.